# Magento 1.9 updating catalog product name changed every single price to 1

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database

Yesterday I wanted to make some changes in every single product name. Basically it was only about changing the position of one string - from the beginning to the end.

What happened was that after successfully changing name to my desire, I found out that my product's price was changed as well. Unfortunately to 1$.

I'm sharing my code, if anyone could explain what happened, why did the price change, I would be grateful.

```
function update_names(){
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    $items = array(
        'Smart Fox'
    );
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $count += 1;
        $name = $product->name;

        foreach ($items as $collection){
            if (strpos($name, $collection) !== false) {
                $name = trim($name);
                $name = str_replace($collection, "PINOKIO ".$collection, $name);
                $name = ucfirst($name);

                $product->setName($name);
                $product->save();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did it changed prices of only those products which you were trying to change the names ? and is there any extension installed for pricing ?

Comment: Nope, no extension for pricing. It chaged all of the edited products

Comment: and have you tested by changing manually from admin ? does it do the same thing

Comment: No, changing it in admin acts correctly. The name is changed as desired

Comment: could you update where you have placed that code either it is independent script or placed in some module etc, and how this code is executed ( observer, direct url etc )

Comment: It is done by adding a button to observer. A button triggers the function